# Posting An Answer

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I been trying to answer this question [discrete GPU not working after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304057/discrete-gpu-not-working-after-update), But when i press **Post your Answer**, Its posting as an **comment**, I have tried several times but still the same

Please have look at this video http://youtu.be/gRz6qtq19yw

Comment: Strange - worked for me. Now I have a "Test" deleted answer.

Comment: @mateo i did 3, 4 times ....let me try again & make video..

Comment: the video is private

Comment: @Private Can you see the video ? ....

Comment: No: "This video is private. If the owner of this video has granted you access, please log in."

Comment: Looks like what you're posting is so short, the site considers it a comment rather than an answer and automatically converts it.

Comment: Now its public http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRz6qtq19yw

Comment: @FEichinger thank you .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments looks like you are trying to post:

> "Have a look at my answer 'answer link here'".

Notice the text "Trivial answer converted to comment".

If you believe this answers the question you could post a overview of what the answer is. Extra info related to the specific question, or if the answers are exact maybe the question is a duplicate.

Anyway, such a short answer gets auto converted - If you believe such an answer is necessary you can "trick" the system with a hidden message such as this:  : can only be seen in edit, between those marks. Use extreme caution as I would not recommend that for your "comment", making that into an answer would probably get downvoted, commented as a link only answer question, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer was too short (it really should have been a comment) that the system auto converted it. Notice the text under the comment:

> Trivial answer converted to comment